# Public Property & Class Not Exposed on WebService

Tags: web-services

I modified a WebService to include a public property and a public class, rebuild, updated the service in my client app.  Neither are accessible by the client app for some reason.  When I launch the test page, I can see them there; but when I use them in code, building breaks.  It seems like the WebService is ignoring my changes or not regenerating.

Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 0):

Web-services only support calling methods, not properties.

You'll have to create GetPropertyName and SetPropertyName methods to wrap up your property.

Comment: What would you possibly do in the setter? The web service instance is destroyed at the end of each method call.

Comment: With WCF you can have singleton instance of a web-service, also - the setter may be writing information to a datastore (XML file, database etc).